# How to find google app engine source code which were deployed two years ago

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, app-engine-flexible

We have a google cloud AppEngine service that was written and deployed by a developer who is no longer with our company (we do still have his login credentials, however). The version is on a custom runtime and a flexible environment, and it was last deployed on April 16, 2018.
Our problem is that this service is intermittently throwing 502/nginx errors and we cannot seem to locate the source code for it. When we go to the debug tab on that version, we see the attached screen. Attempting to redeploy following the instructions in the screenshot errors because there are no source files in our local directory.

Does anyone know if it is possible to find out where this code was deployed from? We have of course scoured our GitLab and cannot find the project there.

[image]

Comment: is your service using a custom runtime? is this service working?

Comment: Yes @JanHernandez

Answer (score 8):

You can try going to App Engine > Instances in your GCP console (https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/instances). Select the correct service from the dropdown and then choose "SSH" on the instance itself.

[image]

A Cloud Shell will open. Do `sudo docker exec -t -i gaeapp /bin/bash` to open the app container ([Access app files in ssh session into google app engine flexible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022421/access-app-files-in-ssh-session-into-google-app-engine-flexible))

Now if you do `ls` you should see the files. However, at this point I don't know how to easily download all of them.

@Jans answer would be far more straight forward to access the files, but `staging.[yourproject].appspot.com` by default will delete files that are older than 14 days

Answer (score 0):

I found that the code of the App engine services is uploaded to folder in Google Cloud storage

1. [Open storage browser](http://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser)
2. go to the folder `staging.[yourproject].appspot.com`
3. check the folder `us.gcr.io` *this may vary depending on the region of appengine*
4. open the folder  `appengine`
5. The files within this folder are TAR files with the source code of your app engine services.

If this folder was deleted, the code cannot be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another option here, a while ago I was working on several ways of doing so and gathered them in a GitHub [repo](https://github.com/bhidalto/gae-source). So I'll leave it here in case if it works for you, hope so!